# Magento removing Media Gallery images

Tags: magento-1.9, product, image, product-images, magmi

I'm using MAGMI to import additional product images, when viewing the product in the admin it has all the image as expected. Reindexing the data does not show any errors either.

However, when I load the product on the frontend, all the images are removed from the database except for the last one and I cannot figure out why.

I've disabled the cache, reindexed the data, tried disabling all extensions and even tried reverting back to the default Magento theme. But the same thing happens no matter what I try.

Any ideas?

Comment: They are removed from the database!? The frontend (core) never touches any image in the frontend, so if this really happens, I think it is some 3rd party module

Comment: That's what I originally thought, but I've disabled every single extension which I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured out what it is.

With MAGMI I have the following in the value replacer plugin:

```
{{ implode(';', array_filter(array({item.image2},{item.image3},{item.image4},{item.image5},{item.image6}))) }}`
```

However, this was causing an issue but I'm not sure why. I've since created a PHP script to just generate the media_gallery column and save it straight to the spreadsheet. This way the import works and doesn't remove images when viewing a product on the frontend.

What's strange is that the above code and the PHP script have the exact same output. But using the value replacer there seems to be something amiss, causing the image to be removed.

Comment: Please mark your answer as solution.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing which comes in my mind, which might helps is https://blackfire.io/ it shows all SQL Querys and afaik the PHP code which fires them